# How to get default math font globally

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

This is the font in math mode in my whole document.

[image]

It doesn't even recall the default font ([math fonts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyBUz.png)). It looks more like `\mathcal{}`, which I used once, didn't like, and quickly removed.

How can I revert math font to default in whole document?

Comment: How about you create a small, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) and add `\listfiles` to your preamble, and post the output after `**File list**` in your `.log` as part of your post in the form of an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/125314/edit). This way we can see what files (and/or fonts) might be loaded that causes this "problem".

Comment: @Werner it really is good way of dealing with such problems! Good to know. *Hacking it down* I got to know that `\usepackage{euler}` changed all my math fonts. I can't use `\mathscr{}` now though... Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: Using `euler` for just `\mathscr` is quite a drastic measure. Do you need only the calligraphic Euler letters?

Comment: @egreg I need it for just a few letters. `euler` being truly an overkill I managed to quickly find `amssymb` which is just more than enough for me. @Werner post an answer about MWE and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: `amssymb` has nothing to do with calligraphic letters. Do you mean `\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}`, instead?

Comment: @egreg this indeed works exactly as planned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `euler` package is discouraged as the package is obsolete and `eulervm` should be used.

However, this package changes *all* math symbols using the Euler fonts. If you only need the calligraphic letters from Euler, there is `eucal`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\begin{document}
Euler calligraphic: $\mathscr{ABCDEF}$

CM calligraphic: $\mathcal{ABCDEF}$
\end{document}
```

With the `mathscr` option, Euler calligraphic is available with `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` continues to use the Computer Modern calligraphic letters.

[image]